# Can we have drives on Harddisk in Linux like windows?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Can we have different drives on Linux as windows ?

In windows  I can found the different drives by clicking the MyComputer Icon , and even i can know the disk capacity of that drive.

Same thing I want to do with Linux .

How can i see the different drives and how can i know the disk space of that drive ?

Comment: You use a tool like gparted.  How you view the contents of the drive depends on the exact distro your using.

Comment: Atleast i want to see the memory allocated to each drive in my Linux . Please explain this

Comment: What do you mean?  Why would system memory be allocated to a drive?

Comment: @Ramhound: "memory" doesn't always mean RAM.

Comment: @grawity - I understand that which is the reason I asked what they meant exactly.  The user will have to clarify what they mean if memory doesn't mean system memory.  Of course I personally have never used memory outside of the context of system memory.

Comment: @Ramhound: ...and "system memory" doesn't mean RAM, either. Disks are memory, and they belong to the system, therefore they also are system memory.

Comment: @grawity - I have **never** heard anyone call the storage provided by a optical disk or hdd to be considerd system memory. Must we have this discussion? There is a reason why physical and virtual memory is a seperate concept, allowing for virtual memroy ( say a system cache ) to be stored on a physical storage device such as a hdd or a flash device using ReadyBoost.

Answer (score 2):

Use `df -h` from the command line:

```
$ df -h -T -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs -x ecryptfs
Filesystem               Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3                ext4       38G   23G   14G  63% /
/dev/sda2                ext4      190M   12M  175M   7% /boot
/dev/sda1                vfat       99M   30M   70M  30% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4                ext4      542G  421G  121G  78% /home
/dev/mapper/luks-backups ext4      962G  639G  323G  67% /mnt/backup
```

In GNOME, right-click a mountpoint and choose "Properties" – or use the System Monitor:

[image] [image]

In KDE, right-click a mountpoint and choose "Properties":

[image]

Or use a partition tool like GParted – it also shows information about not currently mounted partitions, but on the other hand, it cannot display anything about encrypted partitions:

[image]